# Is it possible in Common Lisp to disable return values for specified functions?

Tags: common-lisp, return-value, sbcl

I would like to know whether or not it's possible to disable return values for specified functions. I am using compiler SBCL. I am asking this, because it takes a while to print the return value, and I don't even need it. Any ideas?

OK, it does the job:

```
(progn
  (...)
  t)
```

Also, thanks for `*print-length*`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I avoid the nil printed in the end?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429729/how-can-i-avoid-the-nil-printed-in-the-end)

Answer (score 3):

I find it useful to limit the amount of data printed to my reply by setting the [`*print-length*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pr_lev.htm) variable to a relatively low value in my lisp startup file, like so:

```
(setf *print-length* 20)
```

That way, I do not have to worry too much about functions that return a large number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Using the function `values` it is possible to return zero (or several) values from a function.
`values` returns all it's arguments. Thus a function having `(values)` as it's last form will not return anything, while a function ending with `(values val1 val2 val3)` will return three values. When calling a function returning several values, only the first one (the primary return value) is available in the normal way, while the other ones may be captured using e.g. `multiple-value-bind` See the section on [Return Values](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ag.htm) in the Hyperspec for further details

If you want to limit the output from a function that you can not modify, you can call it like this:

```
(progn
   (function-returning-much-data)
   (values))
```